# how to add dependencies for plugins?

Tags: java, gradle, flyway

I want to use flyway in gradle, how to add dependency for the plugins?

```
plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.2.4"
}
ext {
    mysqlVersion = '8.0.13'
}
dependencies {
        runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}")
}
```

when I run

```
gradle flywayMigrate
```

I got error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project1:flywayClean'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayClean
  Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver => Check whether the jar file is present
  Unable to instantiate class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you see any errors, logs, something that can help us understand where the problem is? It seems to be correct. Also, if you can specify gradle version, etc..

Comment: Please take a look at: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/gradle

Comment: @lealceldeiro I got error like this:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project1:flywayClean'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayClean
  Unable to instantiate JDBC driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver => Check whether the jar file is present
  Unable to instantiate class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: The problem is not adding the flyway plugin, it's related to your database driver, or something related to it. BTW, you can [edit] your question and add this relevant information directly in the post

Comment: @vladwoguer I don't want to use buildscript. https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.flywaydb.flyway

Comment: Instead of `runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}")`, try `compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}")` or `api("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}")`